# AMPScript Custom Functions and ContentAreas

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

I created a blank HTML Template using the blank template called: `my template` under `Content Builder` folder. I created 4 content blocks with the following:

- `data-key="emailfunction" data-label="Email Function">`
- `data-key="emailheader" data-label="Email Header"`
- `data-key="emailcontent" data-label="Email Content"`
- `data-key="emailfooter" data-label="Email Footer"`

I create a template based email from the previously created template called `my email` under `Content Builder` and edited the content area's as follows:

Inside the emailfunction content area, i added a code snippet block with the following:

```
%%[ 
if @number == 10 then 
set @numberEvaluated = "Number equals ten." 
elseif @number > 10 then 
set @numberEvaluated = "Number is greater than ten." 
else 
set @numberEvaluated = "Number is less than ten." 
endif 
]%%
```

and finally inside the `emailcontent` area i added the following code snippet:

```
%%[set @number = 20]%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\emailfunction")=%% 
%%=v(@numberEvaluated)=%%
```

All of this was done as per the SFMC documentation found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334539&type=1&mode=1) as well as other stackexchange pages. The content blocks in the template were made by copy pasting the html since i couldn't find a way via the GUI.

The error i get is:

```
The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a ContentAreaByName function call. Function Call: ContentAreaByName("my contents\emailfunction") See inner exception for details.
Content Area "my contents\emailfunction" could not be found. Client ID: XX Function Name: ContentAreaByName Parameter Name: ContentName Parameter Ordinal: 1 Parameter Type: Text Submitted Value: my contents\emailfunction ClientID: XX JobID: 0 ListID: 0 BatchID: 0 SubcriberID: XX Data Source Type: CustomObject Data Source ID: XX
```

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong, am I creating content area's incorrectly, is there a different meaning than the one in the documentation or am i just providing the wrong path? Thanks guys.

Sample Template: `Content Builder\my template`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      ReadMsgBody{ width: 100%;}
      .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
      .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
      body {-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;margin:0 !important;}
      p { margin: 1em 0;}
      table td { border-collapse: collapse;}
      img {outline:0;}
      a img {border:none;}
      @-ms-viewport{ width: device-width;}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .container {width: 100% !important;}
        .footer { width:auto !important; margin-left:0; }
        .mobile-hidden { display:none !important; }
        .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
        img { max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important; max-height:auto !important;}
        .header img{max-width:100% !important;height:auto !important; max-height:auto !important;}
        .photo img { width:100% !important; max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
        .drop { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; float:left; clear:both;}
        .footerlogo { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; padding-top:15px; float:left; clear:both;}
        .nav4, .nav5, .nav6 { display: none !important; }
        .tableBlock {width:100% !important;}
        .responsive-td {width:100% !important; display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
        .fluid, .fluid-centered {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        .fluid-centered {
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        /* MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
        body { padding: 0px !important; font-size: 16px !important; line-height: 150% !important;}
        h1 { font-size: 22px !important; line-height: normal !important;}
        h2 { font-size: 20px !important; line-height: normal !important;}
        h3 { font-size: 18px !important; line-height: normal !important;}
        .buttonstyles {
          font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif !important;
          font-size: 16px !important;
          color: #FFFFFF !important;
          padding: 10px !important;
        }
        /* END OF MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        .container { width:100% !important; }
        .mobile-hidden { display:none !important; }
        .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
        .photo img { width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
        .nav5, .nav6 { display: none !important;}
        .fluid, .fluid-centered {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        .fluid-centered {
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!--[if mso]>
      <style type="text/css">
          /* Begin Outlook Font Fix */
          body, table, td {
              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
              font-size:16px;
              color:#000000;
              line-height:1;
          }
          /* End Outlook Font Fix */
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; padding: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; font-size: 16px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
    <div style="font-size:0; line-height:0;"><custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"><custom name="usermatch" type="tracking" /></div>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <custom type="header"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" class="container" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table class="tb_properties border_style" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <!-- added padding here -->
                          <td class="content_padding" style="">
                            <!-- end of comment -->
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                              <tr> <!-- AMP Script Function -->
                                <td align="center" class="header" valign="top">
                                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 100%;">
                                                  <div data-type="slot" data-key="emailfunction" data-label="Email Function">
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr> <!-- top slot / header -->
                                <td align="center" class="header" valign="top">
                                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 100%;">
                                                  <div data-type="slot" data-key="emailheader" data-label="Email Header">
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr> <!-- middle slot / content -->
                                <td align="center" class="header" valign="top">
                                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 100%;">
                                                  <div data-type="slot" data-key="emailcontent" data-label="Email Content">
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr> <!-- bottom slot / footer -->
                                <td align="center" class="header" valign="top">
                                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 100%;">
                                                  <div data-type="slot" data-key="emailfooter" data-label="Email Footer">
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <custom type="footer" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using `ContentAreaByName`, which is is only for use with [Classic Content](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2019_update_to_classic_content_end_of_support_plan.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) areas. It does not retrieve content stored in Content Builder. To retrieve content from Content Builder by name, use the [ContentBlockByName](https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbyname/) function.

Source: https://ampscript.guide/contentareabyname/

Replacing the function name in your code and adding correct folder path should fix it:

```
%%[set @number = 20]%%
%%= ContentBlockByName("Content Builder\...\emailfunction")=%% 
%%=v(@numberEvaluated)=%%
```

Comment: That's what i ended up doing; I was trying to figure out if this Classic Content Area was still supported or not. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Note not all Content Builder template types for the content ("emailfunction" above) will necessarily work.  We've found template type Code Snippet to work for us.